# How to change jQuery UI selector of JSON value?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have json file this type

```
    {   
        "id":3,
        "name": "John",
        "group_id": 7,
        "last_name":"Mickel"
    }
```

I need to select last_name by jquery autocomplete.
Not "label" like is default in UI autocomplete but last_name.

Comment: Have you looked at the [custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) demo? It shows how to display any field you'd like

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293878/jquery-renderitem-not-being-called

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It is not nice, but works.

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );

      var results = $.grep( myArray, function(value) {
                    return matcher.test( value.last_name );
            });

      response(results)
   }
})
.data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    console.log("test");
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.last_name+"</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

The `source` function makes it so that the filtering works. The `_renderItem` function makes it so that your custom name actually shows in the list.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eyjEg/

Note, that I belive in some of the earlier versions of jQuery it is actually `.data("autocomplete")`.

Having said all this I also recommend reconsidering changing or transforming your JSON data model to match what the component expects. This will make it simpler and ensure, that you don't get locked into a version of jQuery as the `_renderItem` function is part of the internal API and subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom selector to fill in the data.

```
$("element").autocomplete({
  source: json,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("element").val(ui.item.last_name);
  });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work